# Twisted process is huge

Tags: memory-management, twisted

A Twisted app I have was constantly getting killed due to memory problems.  The program grew in size, consuming all of the system's memory before being shut down by the os.  Restart and repeat.

This is on a virtual server, so I doubled the memory, and the issue resolved - the daemon stabilized at around 1.25GB of memory

Does anyone have advice on how I can best profile this to tell what/where all the memory is getting sucked up into ?

If info on the app helps, I'm using the twisted reactor and internet.timer.TimerService to poll a database for items to update through three 'services'.  the items to process are pushed into a twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList , and their processing occurs in a deferToThread block.  In the deferred process there are a handful of blocking operations ( fetching web pages, etc ) and a lot of HTML parsing ( beautiful soup and other libraries ).  I've suggested the reactor.threadpool size to be 10 and each 'service' defers to thread using a SemaphoreService that has 10 tokens.  I really expected this daemon to max out at around 400MB of memory, not 3x that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a generic share of thoughts how I debug memory leak/usage problems in my twisted applications.
Twisted has a ssh server support, and is something which I add in to almost all of my projects in development. 
The ssh provides a interactive python interpreter access to the method which has python garbage collector available and a number of helper functions which allow me to a) inspect count of the instances from a same class, b) start and stop inspection of changes of that count over time and c) to get all references of that class. The nice thing with the interactive interpreter is that it allows ad-hoc introspection of offending instances, their relation to other objects and the state of process they are in. This so far has always proven a valuable instrument to pinpoint exact location where I have forgot / unforseen the ref release problems in my projects.

Comment: Oh, that's great insight!  Thank you!  I will definitely try that approach!

Comment: A twisted question here below yours, had objgraph recomendation for memory leak discovery. This in reality could be very nice to use in combo with the ssh approach i suggested earlier. There - you have it runtime invoked swiss knife for interactive memory exploration :)